Spring Security controller test cases are failing with 403 status code
My test cases are failing in controller class due to spring security.
    @PostMapping("/{username}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('MEMBER') && #username == authentication.principal.username")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> addWishlist(@Parameter(hidden = true) @RequestHeader("Authorization") String token, @PathVariable String username, @RequestBody MovieDto movie){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(wishlistService.addWishlist(username,movie),HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

testcase
    @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles = "MEMBER", username = "user")
    void testAddWishlist() throws Exception {
        String username = "user";
        MovieDto movieDto = new MovieDto();
        movieDto.setTitle("Movie 1");
        WishlistDto wishlistDto = new WishlistDto();
        wishlistDto.setUsername(username);
        wishlistDto.setMovies(List.of(movieDto));

        when(wishlistService.addWishlist(username, movieDto)).thenReturn(wishlistDto);

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/v1.0/private/wishlist/{username}", username)
                        .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer testtoken")
                        .content("{\"id\":\"1\",\"title\":\"Movie 1\"}")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.movies[0].title").value("Movie 1"));
    }

error

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /api/v1.0/private/wishlist/user
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Authorization:"Bearer testtoken", Content-Length:"28"]
             Body = {"id":"1","title":"Movie 1"}
    Session Attrs = {org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.CSRF_TOKEN=org.springframework.security.web.csrf.DefaultCsrfToken@46bfbbb9, SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT=SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=user, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, CredentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_MEMBER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_MEMBER]]]}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 403
    Error message = Forbidden
          Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"0", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<201> but was:<403>
Expected :201
Actual   :403
<Click to see difference>


    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:637)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:214)
    at com.cts.wishlistservice.controller.WishlistControllerTestMvc.testAddWishlist(WishlistControllerTestMvc.java:102)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1597)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1597)


If you're interested in contributing to the project, your help with testing would be greatly appreciated. I've recently enhanced the microservice with Spring Security, but the test cases are failing. If you can assist with the testing, I'll review and merge your code.
Check out the enhanced source code wishlist-service for more details.
Original source code wishlist-service
Thank you!

My guess is that #username == authentication.principal.username is the culprit for this. You can try debugging on that side in order to figure out what is configured wrong.
